# Group Multi-dimensional Array by Value(a) and sort each Group by Value(b)

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, grouping, usort

I have an array containing fruits and vegetables that are all mixed together. I would like to group each item by their type ie 'vegetable' (indicated by value = 1) or 'fruit'(indicated by value = 2) and then have each item positioned in the order assigned to it.

Here is my starting array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "apples"
    ["position"]=> "1"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "potatoes"
    ["position"]=> "2"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "onions"
    ["position"]=> "1"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "oranges"
    ["position"]=> "3"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "tomatoes"
    ["position"]=> "4"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "grapes"
    ["position"]=> "5"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "avocado"
    ["position"]=> "2"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "bean"
    ["position"]=> "5"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "pineapple"
    ["position"]=> "4"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "pepper"
    ["position"]=> "3"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
}
```

Here is the result I am wanting to achieve:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "onions"
    ["position"]=> "1"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "potatoes"
    ["position"]=> "2"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "pepper"
    ["position"]=> "3"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "tomatoes"
    ["position"]=> "4"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "bean"
    ["position"]=> "5"
    ["basket"]=> "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "apples"
    ["position"]=> "1"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "avocado"
    ["position"]=> "2"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "oranges"
    ["position"]=> "3"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "pineapple"
    ["position"]=> "4"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(16) {
    ["name"]=> "grapes"
    ["position"]=> "5"
    ["basket"]=> "2"
  }
}
```

In the 'hopeful' result, it can be seen that there are **2** groups for the field 'basket', namely **1** & **2** and therefore the array must be "ordered" that it is 'grouped' in sequence.

Finally, each 'group' item must then be sorted in its own sequence.

This is what I have thus far:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {return $a['basket'] - $b['basket'];});
```

Can I adapt this to suit my need?

Comment: how you come to know which one is `fruit` and which one is `vegetable`? in your array there is nothing to distinguish like this

Comment: @AlivetoDie basket seams to be 1 for fruit and 2 for vegetable

Comment: @Alive to Die In reality that is not important. The field to focus on that 'handle' that distinction is the field 'basket'. In other words these items need to be grouped by the 'basket' and each 'basket's' items must then be sorted by their assigned 'position'. Does this help to clarify and answer your question?

Comment: @MacBooc 100% correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in PHP 5.3, one can use an anonymous function:

```
uasort($array, function($a,$b)
    {
        return $a['basket'] - $b['basket'] ?: $a['position'] - $b['position'];
    });
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/p9DSP)

This is combined with solutions provided by B. Desai & Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put condition for same basket and sort position wise while there is same basket

```
function sort_myarray($a,$b)
{
    if($a['basket'] == $b['basket']) 
    {
        return $a['position'] - $b['position']; 
    }
    else {
        return $a['basket'] - $b['basket'];
    }
}
uasort($array,"sort_myarray");
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/3SOHj)

**EDIT**

as Casimir et Hippolyte suggest you can also shorten code by

```
function sort_myarray($a,$b)
{
     return $a['basket'] - $b['basket'] ?: $a['position'] - $b['position'];
}
```

Comment: You can also shorten it to: `function sort_myarray($a,$b) { return $a['basket'] - $b['basket'] ?: $a['position'] - $b['position']; }`

Comment: @B. Desai Thank you! My thanks also to Casimir et Hippolyte and others.

Comment: why it's get downvoted ? @Downvoter can you please explain .so that i can correct my mistake

Comment: @JacquesJoubert. If it solve problem then accept/upvote answer. So that it can help other also

Comment: It is the same answer as mine. Missed by a couple of mins.

Comment: *It is the same answer as mine. Missed by a couple of mins* is not the reason for down vote. its the earlier answer than you @RohitAilani

Comment: @B. Desai I did 'upvote' your solution, however my rep is below 15, so it doesn't get displayed. ):

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach but try this :

```
$a = "your array";

function sort_by_position($a, $b)
{
    return $a['position'] - $b['position'];
}

usort($a, 'sort_by_position');

$b = [];

foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
  $b[$v['basket']][] = $a[$k];
}

print_r($b)
```